# How to set host,port,db and pwd for REDIS?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am working on node.js . I stuck in Memory Leak problem and the solution i got (after surfing) is to use Redis for a single-host Node.js production app. But i am wondering how to set host,port,db and pwd for REDIS ?

Comment: You want to use Redis in what way?  With socket.io or something else?

Comment: I am facing memory leakage problem,i am using Express with sessions in my node.js app. So instead of saving session in express i have to do this task via redis.
If there is any better way then please suggest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the port like this:

```
$ redis-server --port 6380
```

This will get the server up on a Unix domain socket.

As for the "password" part of your question, you can turn the authentication layer that Redis provides by editing the `redis.conf` file. Then clients must send the `AUTH` command to authenticate. Refer to the [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/security) for more info.

Comment: Redis uses numbers for DBs, not names. By default there are 16 DBs with names from 0 to 15. You can switch with the `SELECT` command, ex. `SELECT 1` (the default is `0`). If you want additional DBs you must edit the `redis.conf` file.

Comment: @Vardan Might as well accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: hey @Agis where to write redis command? (for eg in mysql we have to first enter to mysql db by writing mysql -u root -p). how to access redis db? where to write select command?

Comment: Which command are you talking about? If you want to connect to the Redis server and issue commands to it you do it by `$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6380` and issue the commands there.